# Cannot Upgrade SQL Server 2017 Eval

Tags: sql-server, eval, upgrade

I was running SQL Server 2017 CTP on my local Win10 box and I woke up today and it said my eval has expired. So I downloaded SQL Server Standard from MSDN.

**Fix attempt #1**: I downloaded SQL Server Standard from MSDN and on SQL Server Installation Center I chose the Maintenance option.

It asked my which instance I want to upgrade and I chose the instance that had expired.  I followed all the instructions and it says it was successful but when I try to start the instance, the event log shows the same error

> SQL Server evaluation period has expired

**Fix attempt #2**: I download SQL Server 2017 Enterprise and from the SQL Server Installation Center I chose "Upgrade from a previous version of SQL Server".
I got through the install steps until I got to the Feature Rules check where it bombed on SQL Server Service Health Check with this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The message received was unexpected or badly formatted).

**Do I have to uninstall?**

Is the only way to upgrade an eval SQL Server instance by wiping it out? If so, what's the safest way to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this answer in production trying to upgrade to enterprise, whereas in test it was just fine.  It failed at the same spot but I believe the issue was that apps were continuously writing to the DB.  So I had to actually remove the external IP address and reboot and at that point it was fine.